# Get the current scope of a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

Is there a way in Javascript to retrieve the scope of a function from within that function? This would be the same as the closure a subfunction would get. E.g.

```
var foo = "exists";

function myFunc(){
 var bar = "also exists";
 console.log(foo);       // "exists"
 console.log(scope.foo); // undefined
 console.log(scope.bar); // "also exists"
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about `this`?

Comment: In the above code, `this.bar` would be `undefined` rather than `"also exists"`.

Comment: No, you cannot get a reference to a scope. They're implicit.

Comment: One drastically terrible consequence of the ability to get a reference to a scope and use it like an object reference would be that it'd give you the ability to alias local variables. That would make code optimization vastly more difficult.

Comment: to find out what `bar` is from another function you need to `return bar;` from `myFunc()`. Then somewhere else, you can write `var myBar = myFunc(); console.log(myBar); // "also exists"`

Comment: @colecmc, I'm not looking to do this from _another_ function, but from within the _same_ function. The reason is that I'm trying to emulate a closure without having to actually define the subfunction in scope. I should probably post another question on that topic, since it seems it's impossible to pass the local scope.

Comment: I created another question that takes [a higher-level approach to what I was trying to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563195/is-it-possible-in-javascript-to-create-an-external-closure).

Comment: Then all you need is 'bar'. Within 'myFunc', it's global.

Comment: @colecmc, what I was after was a reference to the scope. The example `scope.bar` was just to clarify what I wanted--the ability to access `bar` through the scope, not `bar` itself. :D